# How to get value from as array annotated filed?

Tags: java, casting, annotations

I annotate any field like this:

```
@MyAnnotation("annotation")
public String[] values;
```

and I make so:

```
for(Field field : AnnotatedClass.getClass.getFields())
   if (field.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)){
       // but I don't know how to get values String[] array
       // I try to cast but inconvertible types
   }
```

Thanks for any ideas and help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`field.getAnnotation()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getAnnotation(java.lang.Class)) for this:

```
for (Field f : AnnotatedClass.getClass.getFields())
    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
        MyAnnotation anno = field.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
        String values = anno.value();
    }
 }
```

Comment: **But my annotation is such **

<br/>
`
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)`<br/>
`@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`<br/>
`public @interface Headers {`<br/>
`    String value();
}`